# How to set columns width with several conditions using xlwriter in Python 3

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I have several columns in data frame and code like this to adjust columns width:

```
    # by index
    for idx, col in enumerate(df):
        #series = df[col]            
        if idx <= 1:
            worksheet.set_column(idx+1, idx+1, 7)
        elif idx > 1 and idx < 10:
            worksheet.set_column(idx+1, idx+1, 20)        
        else:
            worksheet.set_column(idx+1, idx+1, 10)
    # by column
    for idx, col in enumerate(df):        
        if col == 'SINGLE_SENTENCE' or col == 'SUMMARY':
            worksheet.set_column(idx, idx+1, 50)
        elif col == 'TOTAL':
            worksheet.set_column(idx, idx+1, 15)
```

All works fine but unfortunately, setting for 'SINGLE_SENTENCE' (D) or 'SUMMARY' (C) fields is weird. I have few cases of using `idx` value:

When I use `worksheet.set_column(idx, idx, 50)` it adjusts column B

When `worksheet.set_column(idx, idx+1, 50)` it adjusts B and C

When `worksheet.set_column(idx+1, idx+2, 50)` it adjusts B and C as well.

When `worksheet.set_column(idx+1, idx+1, 50)` it adjusts D.

Where's logic? If it's a bug how to overcome using column names? It seems something is overriding but how and why - the formatting was the last thing I've changed.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that first unnamed row of df caused the issue.
Replaced: `df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname)`

with

`df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname, index=False)`

Now `worksheet.set_column(idx, idx, 20)` works for `idx` and

`worksheet.set_column(idx, idx+1, 50)` for `col` as a query constraint.

It's working now.